# How to auto auto increase numbers when I call element?

Tags: python, list

I m new to python and experimenting liitle bit. I wrote this code.

```
import random

list_1 = []
a = range(1,1000)
for i in a:
  c = random.randint(1,12)
  list_1.append(c)

d = [*range(1,13)]
new_list = []
**new_list = [d[0], list_1.count(d[0])], [d[1], list_1.count(d[1])], [d[2], list_1.count(d[2])], [d[3], list_1.count(d[3])],[d[4], list_1.count(d[4])],[d[5], list_1.count(d[5])],[d[6], list_1.count(d[6])],[d[7], list_1.count(d[7])],[d[8], list_1.count(d[8])],[d[9], list_1.count(d[9])],[d[10], list_1.count(d[10])],[d[11], list_1.count(d[11])]**
print(new_list)
new_list_s = sorted(new_list, key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True)
print(new_list_s)
```

You can see in highlited area what was I wanted to do. Can you show me how to increase those numbers automatically? Becouse if I will have 10000 entries, it's not possible to write it like this. I was thinking about some loop, new lists as entries, but I think there is simplier method, which I don't know.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`List comprehension` to the rescue! Your highlighted line can be accomplished as `tuple([val,list_1.count(val)] for val in d)`

By the way, do you really intend `new_list` to be a `tuple`? You omitted the outer square brackets, and python turns comma-separated values into a `tuple` even if you leave off the parentheses.

```
import random

list_1 = []
a = range(1,1000)
for i in a:
  c = random.randint(1,12)
  list_1.append(c)

d = [*range(1,13)]
new_list = []

new_list = [d[0], list_1.count(d[0])], [d[1], list_1.count(d[1])], [d[2], list_1.count(d[2])], [d[3], list_1.count(d[3])],[d[4], list_1.count(d[4])],[d[5], list_1.count(d[5])],[d[6], list_1.count(d[6])],[d[7], list_1.count(d[7])],[d[8], list_1.count(d[8])],[d[9], list_1.count(d[9])],[d[10], list_1.count(d[10])],[d[11], list_1.count(d[11])]
new_list2 = tuple([val,list_1.count(val)] for val in d)
print(f"new_list == new_list2? {new_list==new_list2}")

print(f"{new_list=}")
print(f"{new_list2=}")
new_list_s = sorted(new_list, key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True)
print(f"{new_list_s=}")
```

Output:

```
new_list == new_list2? True
new_list=([1, 82], [2, 90], [3, 81], [4, 74], [5, 100], [6, 82], [7, 83], [8, 82], [9, 64], [10, 91], [11, 99], [12, 71])  
new_list2=([1, 82], [2, 90], [3, 81], [4, 74], [5, 100], [6, 82], [7, 83], [8, 82], [9, 64], [10, 91], [11, 99], [12, 71]) 
new_list_s=[[5, 100], [11, 99], [10, 91], [2, 90], [7, 83], [1, 82], [6, 82], [8, 82], [3, 81], [4, 74], [12, 71], [9, 64]]
```

Further reading:

- https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp
- https://www.learnbyexample.org/python-list-comprehension/
- https://www.learnbyexample.org/python-dictionary-comprehension/